# Trigger para atualizar data de data de modificação no firebird

Tags: firebird, trigger

Tenho uma tabela de clientes com os campos de **Data de Cadastro do Registro** e **Data de Modificação do Registro** alguém saberia como fazer para criar uma `trigger` que atualiza a coluna de **Data de Modificação** dessa tabela de clientes toda vez que uma linha for alterada, até agora pensei em algo parecido com isso aqui:

```
CREATE trigger TBCLIENTE_DATAMODIFICACAO for TB_CLIENTE
active before update position 0
AS
begin
  update TB_CLIENTE set TB_CLIENTE.DATA_MODIFICACAO = current_date where TB_CLIENTE.CODIGO = ????;
end
```

Onde o `????` é um paramêtro que eu não consigo colocar corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom pessoal, graças a dica do amigo Anthony Accioly, eu consegui resolver meu problema, acredito que a minha estratégia funcionou bem com o seguinte código:

```
CREATE trigger TBCLIENTE_DATAMODIFICACAO for TB_CLIENTE
active before update position 0
AS
begin
  if (new.DATA_MODIFICACAO = CURRENT_DATE) then
    begin
      /*NÃO FAZ NADA PORQUE A DATA FOI ATUALIZADA*/
    end
  else
    begin
      update TB_CLIENTE set TB_CLIENTE.DATA_MODIFICACAO = CURRENT_DATE where TB_CLIENTE.CODIGO = new.CODIGO;
    end
end
```

Com isso o **IF** verifica se a **Data de Modificação** na atualização do registro é igual a data atual, caso a expressão seja verdadeira significa que o registro já foi modificado hoje, então ele ignora o *statement* caso contrário ele atualiza a data de modificação para a **data atual**

Comment: Lima, eu ainda acho que setar `new.DATA_MODIFICACAO` é uma estratégia melhor do que o *update*. Isso evita rodar o *trigger* para não fazer nada uma segunda vez.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo prático Antony?

Comment: A minha resposta é o exemplo prático. A única diferença no seu caso é que você deve trocar o `if (new.DATA_MODIFICACAO is null)` por `if (new.DATA_MODIFICACAO <> CURRENT_DATE)`. Dessa forma você sempre persiste a data atual sem passar duas vezes pelo *trigger* (isso é, sem fazer um *update* extra).

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a afirmação do Julio, executar um *statement* de *update* no *trigger* não é uma ideia muito boa. Se isso fosse permitido no seu caso você entraria em *loop* tentando atualizar a data da última modificação. Dito isso, você sempre pode usar uma sintaxe modificando o valor da variável `new` no *trigger*:

```sql
CREATE trigger TBCLIENTE_DATAMODIFICACAO for TB_CLIENTE
active before update position 0
AS
begin
  if (new.DATA_MODIFICACAO is null)
    then new.DATA_MODIFICACAO = current_date;
end
```

Veja que usei um `if` para verificar se a `DATA_MODIFICACAO` não está preenchida. Usando esse `if` o usuário pode entrar com uma data de modificação manualmente se assim desejar. Se isso não for desejável (i.e., você deseja que a `DATA_MODIFICACAO` seja substituída por `current_date`) basta remover o `if`.

---

**Fonte:** [The Firebird FAQ - How to get the timestamp of last record change?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq77/)

Comment: Irei tentar fazer um procedimento parecido aqui, mudando a situação e em breve darei o feedback

Answer (score -1):

Você não poderá fazer isso porque o próprio sgbd impedirá. Se você conseguisse, iria criar um loop infinito!

Comment: Humm... Essa afirmação não é totalmente verdadeira. Com certeza executar um  *statement* de *update* criaria um *loop*. Por outro lado, como esse é um trigger *before update* podemos simplesmente trocar o valor do *new*.